# An error in python

Tags: python

im new..
my script is pretty long so I'll write down the specific parts.

```
str= ''
#str is a long DNA sequence

def FIND_UPPER(str):
    global x
    x=str.upper()
    y=0
    while y>(-1):
        y=x.find('CTTTGATTCCT')
        z=x[y+11:y+22]
        x=x[y+23:]

        variability(z)

#variability is another function

FIND_UPPER(str)
```

and then I get this message:

> list indices must be integers, not str

about those lines:

```
variability(z)
FIND UPPER(str)
```

How can I fix this?
thanks

**edit:**
this is variability:

```
A=[0]*10
C=[0]*10
T=[0]*10
G=[0]*10

def variability(z):
    for i in z:
        if i=='A': 
            A[i]=A[i]+1
            i=i+1

        elif i=='T':
            T[i]=T[i]+1
            i=i+1

        elif i=='C':
            C[i]=C[i]+1
            i=i+1

        elif i=='G':
            G[i]=G[i]+1
            i=i+1

    return G
    return C
    return T
    return A
```

---

I fixed it, can u tell me if I got u right?
:

```
def variability(z):
    for i in range(len(z)):
        if i=='A': 
            A[i]=z[i]
            A[i]+=1
            i+=1

        elif i=='T':
            T[i]=z[i]
            T[i]+=1
            i+=1

        elif i=='C':
            C[i]=z[i]
            C[i]+=1
            i+=1

        elif i=='G':
            G[i]=z[i]
            G[i]+=1
            i+=1

    return G,C,T,A
```

Comment: Could you please show us `variability`?

Comment: And the actual traceback showing what the error refers to. It's not just pointless noise, it actually tells you how to debug the issue.

Comment: First thing - multiple `return` statements in a function won't work. Only the first will be executed, because it breaks out of the function. If you want to return multiple things, try using a tuple.

Comment: Second thing - `i = i+1` can be written as `i += 1` instead, which is the norm.

Answer (score 3):

```
def variability(z):
    for i in z:
        if i=='A': 
            A[i]=A[i]+1
            i=i+1
```

Assume `i == 'A'`, then `A[i]` is actually translated to `A['A']` which returns:

`list indices must be integers, not str`

Which means you can't access a list by a string index, list indices are integers.

Moreover, Python doesn't support multiple return statements:

```
return G
return C
return T
return A
```

This will always return G

If you want to return all of these values, then replace it with:

```
return G,C,T,A
```

The above return statements returns a `tuple` consists `G,C,T,A`

If you want to return just one, place each `return` statement inside your `elif` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

In the loop you have to do something like:

```
for i in range(len(z)):
    letter = A[i]
```

If you iterate over range function result, "i" will take numeric values. If you iterate over the string i will take each character of the string

An then compare variable "letter"

```
if letter == 'A':
    ...
```

Be careful in the variability function, only the value in the first return statement will be returned.

Comment: Sure, on a side note, I would use `xrange`.

Comment: `range` in Python 3.x is equivalent to `xrange`. On another side note, I would use `for index, letter in enumerate(z):` instead, as more idiomatic.